# FragmentDialog different design of UI

Tags: android, android-layout

I try launch samples as this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html), but I have different design of UI. I have this:

[image]

But I want have new design as this:

[image]

I launch my project on simulator with android api 14.

How can I use the new design as last image?

Answer (score -1):

@WebnetMobile.com friend u can have this view by using a list view and then using a style such that editText element must have width fill parent and hint must have a style element and this elemnt style should have the gravity of 1 and and top left with text size small as u needed (keep looking in your xml and fit it accordingly). also for text color use color:# for hex code u can see on internet to find out the hex code of your desired answer